# Unable to get traceId when using @feignClient

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, openfeign

I have 2 services S1 and S2. Calling S2 using annotated Feign client(@FeignClient) from S1. The issue is, I am unable to get traceId in S2.

But when I try to call S2 using RestTemplate it works.

Any help will be appreciated

**Edited**:

I have find out the cause actually I am using Feign.Builder below is sample code which builds fiegn client.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feign.hystrix.enabled")
    public Feign.Builder feignHystrixBuilder() {
        SetterFactory setterFactory = new SetterFactory() {
            @Override
            public HystrixCommand.Setter create(Target<?> target, Method method) {
                String groupKey = target.name();
                String commandKey = target.name();
                return HystrixCommand.Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(groupKey))
                    .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(commandKey));
            }
        };
        return HystrixFeign.builder().setterFactory(setterFactory);
    }
```

Actually due to above config.. SleuthFeignHystrixBuilder is not invoked.
I need to set HysterixCommandKey in my format.. thats why need above config.

How can it work with spring-sleuth ?

Comment: Can you provide any meaningful information? Which version of sleuth are you using? How do you use feign etc?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have edited the questions

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Spring's BeanPostProcessor interface and then set 'setterFactory'. Refer to below sample code

```
@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

    if(bean instanceof HystrixFeign.Builder) {

        ((HystrixFeign.Builder)bean).setterFactory(new SetterFactory() {
            @Override
            public HystrixCommand.Setter create(Target<?> target, Method method) {
                String groupKey = target.name();
                String commandKey = target.name();
                return HystrixCommand.Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(groupKey))
                    .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(commandKey));
            }
        });

    }
    return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line simply be `return bean;` ?  I know the interface has a default method that does exactly that, this seems a bit cumbersome.